# Is there a way to loop through an array to grab path and driver description to an if statement

Tags: powershell

Following script gets an array/tuple of registry values. I want to loop through each value and get value matching expression:

```
$values = @("Name",$value1,$value2,$value3,$value4,$value5,$value6,$value7,$value8,$value9)

$value1 = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000" -name "DriverDesc" | out-string
$value2 = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0001" -name "DriverDesc" | out-string
$value3 = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0002" -name "DriverDesc" | out-string
$value4 = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0003" -name "DriverDesc" | out-string
$value5 = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0004" -name "DriverDesc" | out-string
$value6 = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0005" -name "DriverDesc" | out-string
$value7 = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0006" -name "DriverDesc" | out-string
$value8 = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0007" -name "DriverDesc" | out-string
$value9 = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0008" -name "DriverDesc" | out-string

if ($values -like "*Ethernet*")
{
    Get-Item $values # including the path
}
```

Comment: so i am trying to loop through the registry to grab a driver description like ethernet and the path so i can modify a registry entry specifically the network adapter

Comment: [Edit] the question. Format the code, move the problem description into the question body and write better a subject. Show an example of desired output if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop through a specific path, you can use `Get-ChildItem` with `ForEach-Object`.
Then, you can use `Get-ItemProperty` and check values in registry key properties.

```
Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\000*" | ForEach-Object {
    $regkey = (Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath) 
    if ($regkey.DriverDesc -like "*Ethernet*"){
        #Set-ItemProperty ...
    }
}
```